# $a,b,c\ge0$ prove $\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}\ge\frac{1}{a+b+c}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c\ge0: ab+bc+ca>0$. Prove that: $$\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}\ge\frac{1}{a+b+c}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}$$

My attempt: Using C-S inequality:$$\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}\ge\frac{9}{2(a+b+c)}$$ But $$\frac{9}{2(a+b+c)}\le \frac{2}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}$$
Also, I try denote $f(a,b,c)=\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}-\frac{1}{a+b+c}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}$ and set $f(0,b,c)=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{bc}}$.

I want $f(a,b,c)\ge f(0,b,c)\ge0$. Here is my work: $f(a,b,c)- f(0,b,c)=\frac{-a}{a+b}+\frac{-a}{a+c}+2\left(\frac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}-\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{bc(ab+bc+ca)}}\right)-\frac{1}{a+b+c}$

But the rest seems complicated to me. I need your help to full my idea. Is there any better choice? Thanks for helping.

Comment: AM-GM maybe? 10chars

Comment: Can you tell more?

Comment: Given that the inequalities you post are not that standard, It is helpful for you to determine the equality condition (EG $(1, 1, 0)$), which would explain why your CS doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks @CalvinLin a lot. So my second approach is effective, isn't it?

Comment: Can anyone think of my second idea?

Comment: @Mars For your second approach, I didn't get that expression. EG I was expecting to see a $ - 1/b$. (Maybe you factored it into the surds expression. It didn't seem to lead anywhere, so I didn't follow through with it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG $ab+bc+ca=1$, then
$$\Longleftrightarrow 
\dfrac{1}{a+b}+\dfrac{1}{a+b}+\dfrac{1}{c+a}-\dfrac{1}{a+b+c}\ge 2$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{a+b+c}{a+b}+\dfrac{a+b+c}{b+c}+\dfrac{a+b+c}{c+a}-1\ge 2(a+b+c)$$
or
$$2+\dfrac{c}{a+b}+\dfrac{a}{b+c}+\dfrac{b}{a+c}\ge 2(a+b+c)$$
since Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$\dfrac{c}{a+b}+\dfrac{a}{b+c}+\dfrac{b}{a+c}\ge\dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{2(ab+bc+ac)}=\dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{2}$$
It suffices to show that:
$$2+\dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{2}\ge 2(a+b+c)$$ it is clear

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: As an aside, for a slightly faster proof, we can sum the cyclic inequalities $ (a+b) c + c/(a+b) \geq  2c$.